# How to change default text color using custom theme?

Tags: android, colors, android-theme

What I'm trying should be quite easy with themes, but I can't find out how to:
I want all text to be white by default in my app.
I created a custom theme in theme.xml:

```
<style name="Theme" parent="@android:Theme">
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Theme" parent="@android:TextAppearance.Theme">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffffff</item>
</style>
```

and set it for the whole application:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme">
```

But labels are still black.
What's missing?

PS: How can I additionally define styles for different text sizes, to be applied per widget?
Is something like that correct?

```
<style name="Theme.smallText">
    <item name="android:textSize">12dp</item>
</style>
```

**update**

I took a look at *themes.xml* in Android SDK, it shows how to set the text style for a theme:

```
<item name="textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance</item>
```

In my case it should work with this definition:

```
<style name="Theme" parent="@android:Theme">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/MyText</item>
</style>

<style name="MyText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffffff</item>
</style>
```

However, it is still not working.

Here's [another post](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/2897ccd0884546b9) about this same issue.

Comment: Your update says "still not working". Is it throwing any errors or is the text style just not taking effect?

Answer (score 72):

In your `Manifest` you need to reference the name of the `style` that has the text color `item` inside it. Right now you are just referencing an empty `style`. So in your theme.xml do only this `style`:

```
<style name="Theme" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffffff</item>
</style>
```

And keep you reference to in the `Manifest` the same (`android:theme="@style/Theme"`)

**EDIT**:

theme.xml:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12dp</item>
</style>
```

Manifest:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
```

Notice I combine the text color and size into the same `style`. Also, I changed the name of the theme to MyTheme and am now referencing that in the `Manifest`. And I changed to `@android:style/TextAppearance` for the `parent` value.

Comment: If I do this, I get Exception "Resource is not a ColorStateList". I use sub-styles (?): <style name="BCGTheme.smallText"><item name="android:textSize">12sp</item></style>. Is this still ok with this change?

Comment: You say "Right now you are just referencing an empty style." Does that mean that android:Theme is an empty style? Weird...

Comment: Sorry, empty, wasn't the right word. You're just not doing anything to the `android:Theme` so when you use it in the `Manifest`, it is just applying the same theme as usual. See my edit for what your code should look like.

Comment: One more small change. Try what I did above and let us know how it works.

Comment: sry, this doesn't work. I get "Error inflating class android.widget.TextView. Reason: Resource is not a ColorStateList

Comment: That is a different problem than the one we are addressing. It sounds like you are setting the `textColor` XML attribute in a `TextView` to the theme, which is unnecessary, since we are applying the theme to all text in your app through the `Manifest`. You should remove any lines where you are changing the `textColor` on an individual `TextView`

Comment: no, I don't manually set textColor anywhere. I guess the Exception is thrown by an implicit call to it. In my understanding, a style is a set of attributes for a specific view. I guess a style for textAppearance can't be set as theme for the whole app.

Comment: Yeah I tested it and got the same thing but when I removed the parent attr. from the style it worked, but then I guess you'd lose all your inherited text appearance styles. Maybe tinker with that anyway.

Comment: @didi_X8 Dug around some more and found one or two examples of people that had the same issue with inheriting text appearance. So maybe it is a bug. You could try just removing the `parent` attribute of the style. Maybe text does not need to inherit from anything.

Comment: indeed I also start thinking it's just not working better. I would like to acknowledge your effort with some points, but can't mark your answer as correct bcs this code leads to app crash here. Will give you an upvote. Thanks anyway!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work at all, since it's using `@android:style/TextAppearance` as the parent for the whole app's theme. Crashes with InflateException / InvocationTargetException / UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x2.

Comment: Please use 12sp instead of 12dp for text size, then the text size can be changed in system settings for user who have poor eyesight.

Answer (score 54):

When you create an App, a file called styles.xml will be created in your res/values folder. If you change the styles, you can change the background, text color, etc for all your layouts. That way you don’t have to go into each individual layout and change the it manually.

styles.xml:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<style name="Theme.AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:editTextColor">#295055</item> 
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#295055</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#295055</item>
    <item name="android:textColorTertiary">#295055</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">#295055</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">#295055</item>
    <item name="android:textColorTertiaryInverse">#295055</item>

     <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/custom_background</item>        
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

`parent="@android:style/Theme.Light"` is Google’s native colors. Here is a reference of what the native styles are:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml

**The default Android style is also called “Theme”. So you calling it Theme probably confused the program.**

`name="Theme.AppBaseTheme"` means that you are creating a style that inherits all the styles from `parent="@android:style/Theme.Light"`.
This part you can ignore unless you want to inherit from AppBaseTheme again. =     `<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">`

@drawable/custom_background is a custom image I put in the drawable’s folder. It is a 300x300 png image.

#295055 is a dark blue color.

My code changes the background and text color. For Button text, please look through Google’s native stlyes (the link I gave u above).

Then in Android Manifest, remember to include the code:

```
<application
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppBaseTheme">
```

Comment: Nice extended answer, which explains more than koopaking3. However, the items's you've included in your Theme.AppBaseTheme do not include the basic 'android:textColor'. The color of most textviews in my app are determined by this attribute, not by eg. android:textColorPrimary.

Comment: This changes the color globally across the entire app, that way you don't have to set the attribute in each TextView. This changes the default settings across the entire app.

Comment: It does not (or at least not for me), that's what I tried to explain. And I didn't set the attribute in any of my textviews.

Comment: You can send your code to me at gc.genechuang@gmail.com. I'll take a look at it

Comment: This code fixes my issue in preference screen(Changing secondary text). I just found out that there is this secondary item. Thanks @Gene <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#295055</item>

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 27):

You can't use `@android:style/TextAppearance` as the parent for the whole app's theme; that's why [koopaking3's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9593575/56285) seems quite broken.

To **change default text colour everywhere in your app** using a custom theme, try something like this.
Works at least on Android 4.0+ (API level 14+).

`res/values/themes.xml`:

```
<resources>    
    <style name="MyAppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <!-- Change default text colour from dark grey to black -->
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Manifest:

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme">
```

#### Update

A shortcoming with the above is that also *disabled* Action Bar overflow menu items use the default colour, instead of being greyed out. (Of course, if you don't use disabled menu items anywhere in your app, this may not matter.)

As I learned [by asking this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21279319/changing-default-text-colour-and-still-showing-disabled-menu-items-in-different), a better way is to define the colour using a **drawable**:

```
<item name="android:textColor">@drawable/default_text_color</item>
```

...with `res/drawable/default_text_color.xml` specifying separate `state_enabled="false"` colour:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
    <item android:color="@android:color/black"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: This solution is very clean. The problem is the text inside a `RadioButton`, `CheckBox`, `Switch`, `EditText`... Any idea?

Comment: I'm going to answer my own question. You can use `android:textColorPrimaryDisableOnly` for `RadioButton`, `CheckBox`, `Switch`. And You can use `android:editTextColor` and `android:textColorHint` for `EditText`. Related question: [How to change default color in all texts in my Android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13142473/842697)

Answer (score 1):

Check if your activity layout *overrides* the theme, look for your activity layout located at `layout/*your_activity*.xml` and look for **TextView** that contains `android:textColor="(some hex code")` something like that on activity layout, and remove it. Then run your code again.

Answer (score -2):

```
    <style name="Mytext" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"> 
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item> 
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item> 
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
</style>
```

try this one ...