# How to change default color in all texts in my Android application?

Tags: android, colors, android-edittext, android-button, android-theme

I would like to change all color texts in my application.
So I wrote this code and I set my theme in the manifest:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

But only TextView texts are in white. I would like Button and EditText to be in white too.

Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: To solve my problem I used textColorPrimary for EditView and Ahmad solution for button color. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your Theme:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
     <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
     <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonTheme</item>
  </style>
```

And this is how you can set your Button Theme:

```
<style name="ButtonTheme" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
     <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

And also do this with EditTexts etc.

Answer (score 25):

I think most of the widget styles build off of these:

```
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/primary_text_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/secondary_text_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorTertiary">@android:color/tertiary_text_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@android:color/primary_text_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">@android:color/secondary_text_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColorTertiaryInverse">@android:color/tertiary_text_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryDisableOnly">@android:color/primary_text_dark_disable_only</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverseDisableOnly">@android:color/primary_text_light_disable_only</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryNoDisable">@android:color/primary_text_dark_nodisable</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondaryNoDisable">@android:color/secondary_text_dark_nodisable</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverseNoDisable">@android:color/primary_text_light_nodisable</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverseNoDisable">@android:color/secondary_text_light_nodisable</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/hint_foreground_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHintInverse">@android:color/hint_foreground_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSearchUrl">@android:color/search_url_text</item>
```

Override the values as needed.

Comment: Remember that you need to write `android:` before any of this names. For example: `android:textColorPrimary`

Answer (score -6):

Assign color to button text

```
<Button android:textColor="#FFFFFF"></Button>
```