# textview color got changed after changing the theame to app compat

Tags: android, textview, material-design

I am trying to upgrade my app to support Material design on pre-lollipop devices, for this i have added android support library v7 and changed my app's style from `android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` to `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`. Now my `MainActivity` extends `ActionBarActivity` of support library along with this I have changed my action bar to tool bar.

Till here all work good and it shows new drawer toggle icon with animation but in my entire app all text color has been changed from **`Black`** to **`White`** and now I have no clue from where I have to change. Do I have to change it in my every layout?

I am using Android studio with following configuration.

**`Build.gradle`**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+"

}
```

**`Style.xml`**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">false</item>
</style>
```

**`Layout.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/TopLevelActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        style="@style/Default"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_label"
            style="@style/SectionHeader.First"
            android:text="@string/name"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            style="@style/Text.SingleLine" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email_label"
            style="@style/SectionHeader"
            android:text="@string/email" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            style="@style/Text.SingleLine" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/app_version_label"
            style="@style/SectionHeader"
            android:text="@string/app_version" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/app_version"
            style="@style/Text.SingleLine" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/customer_support_label"
            style="@style/SectionHeader"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:text="@string/customer_support" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/customer_support_phone"
            style="@style/Text.SingleLine"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:autoLink="all" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/customer_support_email"
            style="@style/Text.SingleLine"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:autoLink="all" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/alarm_service_toggle"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small_padding"
            style="@style/Default" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/Text.SingleLine"
            android:textColor="@android:color/tertiary_text_light"
            android:text="@string/switch_location_sub_message" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/capture_logs"
            style="@style/Default"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/medium_padding"
            android:text="@string/capture_logs" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/logout"
            style="@style/Default"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/medium_padding"
            android:text="@string/logout" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Please let me know if any other inputs are required from me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` instead of `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`.

Answer (score 1):

In theme you have to define text color

OR

```
   SetTextColor(Color.colorname);
```

from java at run time

OR

in xml android:textColor="#color code"

Comment: so are you trying to say is now default color is white instead of black and i have to change all my layouts?

Comment: you need to change color in your theme
      <style name="Theme" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffffff</item>
</style>
or try this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142098/how-to-change-default-color-in-all-texts-in-my-android-application

Comment: thanks for the reply. your answer is an alternative of accepted answer so +1 for your answer also.