# Android :apply textColor to a layout

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to apply a textColor to a layout as opposed to a textView. Is this possible or is textView the only method that can apply a text color via xml?

Comment: can you please explain more what you actually want?

Comment: he wants to apply the text color to the opposed color of the given screen.

Comment: A layout does not have text so the question makes no sense!  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Im trying to generically apply a text color to a screen as opposed to  specifying text color in in each individual textView.

Comment: then you should apply a style to all of your textviews

Comment: I think you want to change the textcolor of your whole app instead of the default textcolor. Look at this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593133/change-default-text-color

Answer (score 1):

here is link of setting textcolor by coding

[How to set the text color of TextView in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602902/how-to-set-text-color-of-textview-by-coding)

and in xml youu can do it in a text view.

```
android:textColor="#000000"
```

hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Implement custom styles and set style on your UI elements you want to have another textcolor on. You may also be able to make some custom themes that you can set for your layout, but I'm not sure if or how that works. But you can certainly get some ideas from here [Android developer styles and themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).