# Need help in changing text color in android app

Tags: android

In the below code, how would i change it so i can make the font color black? This is driving me crazy. please help!

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
 <PreferenceCategory
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_bluetooth"
    android:title="@string/settings_bluetooth" >
    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
                       android:fragment="no.nordicsemi.android.nrftemp.fragment.SettingsFragmetn$BluetoothSettingsFragment"
        android:key="settings_scan_in_background"
        android:summary="@string/settings_scan_in_background_summary"
        android:title="@string/settings_scan_in_background_title"/>

    <ListPreference
        android:dependency="settings_scan_in_background"
        android:entries="@array/settings_periods"
        android:entryValues="@array/settings_periods_values"
        android:key="settings_scan_interval"
        android:defaultValue="300000"
        android:title="@string/settings_scan_period_title" />
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/settings_about" >
    <no.nordicsemi.android.nrftemp.fragment.AboutPreference android:title="@string/settings_about_title" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

Comment: What text are you talking about exactly?

Comment: all the android:title strings, currently they are are grey, while around my whole app the text is black

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593133/how-to-change-default-text-color-using-custom-theme) answer about styles and themes.

More specifically this:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: do i add it to the code i pasted, or do i refrerence it from the styles.xml which has my apperence set?

Comment: Reference the style:
So for example inside you code listpreferences just reference:
style="@style/styleName"

Comment: for example can i add this to end of listpreference code.?
android:style="@style/TextAppearance.Small"

Comment: my good man, i got closer to solving the issue, now my preference headers are the color i want them to be, but the subtext under them are still grey. i tried these to get them to be black, but non worked, any suggestions?
        <item name="android:textColorLink">@color/textColor</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/textColor</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/textColor</item>

Comment: Any chance you can link me to an image of the layout? If you are using a layout for each item in your list then you will need to reference the style in that xml file.