# How to change color of text in whole application by changing theme

Tags: android, android-studio

I beginner in UI designing, I'm trying to build an app that can change theme as an additional option. As the theme switches to black ToolBar and TabLayout Turns black and I'm using default font color "Black" as is suitable for white theme.
Please help me, how to set text color such that it will change in theme.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change default text color using custom theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593133/how-to-change-default-text-color-using-custom-theme)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Following

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
}
```

Where Theme is your Style that is to Be Implemented

[How to change app default theme to a different app theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19186235/how-to-change-app-default-theme-to-a-different-app-theme)

[Check these Doc Please](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#setTheme%28int%29)

Comment: I have edited my question, sorry for previous question. help me solve this problem

Comment: In your Theme use the variable textColor. Apply that Style to the textView.