# Set text color of all elements in Activity

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to change the complete textColor of every element(Checkboxes,RadioButtons,etc..) in a activity ?

```
CheckBox check = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
check.setTextColor(Color.rgb(Rot,Gruen,Blau));
```

this is how i change the color of the checkbox but i want change all the elements, is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change default text color using custom theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593133/how-to-change-default-text-color-using-custom-theme)

Comment: Not duplicate ! I am trying to change the color in the .java file not the xml files.

Comment: Set the theme in the .java file then?

Comment: maybe by just keeping track of present color in SHARED pref for the user and using a method which posses all the Views setColorProperty there for each activity of yours and changing it after ViewLoad! I mean using it in ONCREATE after setting the design

Comment: or maybe inflation the whole design and getting the rootView group and setting up the textColor property for all Views again in the ONCREATE method after setting the contentVirw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it may help to solve your problem.

```
private void setAppFontColor(ViewGroup mContainer, int color) {
    if (mContainer == null || color == 0)
        return;

    final int mCount = mContainer.getChildCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < mCount; ++i) {
        final View mChild = mContainer.getChildAt(i);
        if (mChild instanceof TextView) {
            ((TextView) mChild).setTextColor(color);
        } else if (mChild instanceof Button) {
            ((Button) mChild).setTextColor(color);
        } else if (mChild instanceof ViewGroup) {
            setAppFontColor((ViewGroup) mChild, color);
        }
    }
}
```

Where

```
ViewGroup mContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
```

Comment: Works perfect ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

yes,add `textColorSecondary` to your activity theme

```
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">yourcolor</item>
```